# git pull error: sublime -w: sublime: command not found

Tags: git, github

I've been trying to pull from a repo and I've been getting this error and can't figure it out. Any help in the right direction is appreciated!

```
 sublime -w: sublime: command not found
 error: There was a problem with the editor 'sublime -w'.
 Not committing merge; use 'git commit' to complete the merge.
```

Answer (score 1):

Probably Git is configured to use `sublime` as editor and it is not able to find it.

If you really want to use Sublime as editor check if it is really installed and it is in your  `PATH`.

Alternatively, you can change the editor git uses with this command (replace `vim` with your preferred editor: `emacs`, `nano`, etc):

```
git config --global core.editor "vim"
```

**Edit:** Also the correct command to launch Sublime Text in terminal is `subl` (thanks  QuantumPhi)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Looking at my bash_profile, I see my path is: export PATH=$PATH:~/.gem/ruby/1.8/bin:/opt/nginx/sbin . When I changed it to export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH , I get an error on the command line. Any ideas?

Comment: Don't change that line. Just add at the end of the file `PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin`

Comment: Still getting the same error (sublime -w). I'm going to dive into it a little deeper tonight. Thanks for your help.

Comment: In console, Sublime text is represented by `subl`, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Sublime Text needs to be launched with the `subl` line instead of `sublime`, and will need to be in your `PATH`.

You can check if it's present by running the commands `which subl` (to show you the path of the file on the computer) or `subl -n` (to launch a new window in Sublime Text).

To fix your `git` editor you can run `git config --global core.editor "subl"`

Source: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/osx_command_line.html